# Adding fast ethernet ports to a server in packet tracer

Tags: cisco

How can I add more than 2 fast ethernet ports to a server in packet tracer?

Comment: Packet tracer is very simple, only designed to get you through the CCNA exam. Many things are missing from it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't.

The server has 2 slot to put any interface card and packet tracer propose only single port cards.

Available cards are:

- WMP300N: WiFi 2.4 Ghz
- PT-HOST-NM-1CE:   Copper Ethernet (10Mb).
- PT-HOST-NM-1CFE:  Copper Fast Ethernet (100Mb)
- PT-HOST-NM-1CGE:  Copper Gigabit Ethernet (1000Mb)
- PT-HOST-NM-1FFE:  Fiber  Fast Ethernet (100Mb)
- PT-HOST-NM-1FGE:  Fiber  Gigabit Ethernet (1000Mb)
- PT-HOST-NW-1W:    WiFi 2.4 Ghz (equivalent to WMP300N)
- PT-HOST-NW-1W-A:  WiFi 5 Ghz
- PT-HOST-NM-1W-AC: WiFi 2.4 and 5 Ghz
- PT-HOST-NM-3G/4G: Cellular 3G / 4G

[image: Cisco PacketTracer server]

Verified with Cisco Packet Tracer 7.3.0 MacOs version.